# Choosing the best method to test how random are P/RNGs

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, random-generation, randomness

[1]
I'm testing some P/RNGs algorithms, so in order to see how normally distributed are the values obtained by these Random Number Generators (resp. Pseudo-), which method suits best? Is drawing the Normal Distribution Curve would be sufficient? Or doing a Chi-squared test is preferable?

By normally distributed, I mean purely random values (or pseudo-random since I am using pseudo-random number generators).

[2]
Please correct my statements if I am mistaken:

- In a Chi-squared test, by accepting the null hypothesis, we conclude that there is no correlation between the generated values and therefore they are "purely" random (resp. pseudo-random)
- If the obtained normal distribution curve is a Bell-shaped curve, can we reach the same previous conclusion?

Comment: You seem to conflate "random" with "normal", "uniform", and/or "no correlation." It is important to understand the differences among those things.  Since uniform variates and normal variates are easily converted between each other, I have presumed your interest is in testing an RNG rather than discussing these distinctions.

Comment: Shouldn't randomly drawn variables be uniformly distributed within a given interval rather than following a bell.shaped distribution?

Comment: "Randomly drawn" does not automatically mean *uniform*.  Although most RNGs indeed try to produce uniformly distributed (and independent) values, not all of them are intended to do so.  The critical properties you want of an RNG are *independence* and *having a common distribution*.  If that common distribution is non-uniform, it's not a serious problem because it's easily converted to a uniform one.  The concepts of "random", "uniform", and "uncorrelated" are sharply distinguished in statistics and have little in common with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the information, very helpful. Although I wonder how far the presence (or absence) of uniformity in randomly generated numbers can affect simulation results. Most simulators use RNG.s  following a bell-shaped distro,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with running [NIST test suite](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/random_number.html#RNG%20Test) on your RNG. If you're using a vendor product then chances are that it has already been tested for randomness.

NIST suite has a lot of different tests, there's no need to invent your own unless the application is very unusual.